# canvasで書いた線を曲線にしたい

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

canvasで線を書くときに、
太字になるとどうしても線が荒くなり綺麗な曲線を描けません。

下記参照
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下のリンクのサイトでは、綺麗な曲線になっていて、どのように書かれているのか分からず、
同じような曲線を描きたいのですが、
どのようなjsの記述が必要でしょうか。

[リンクの説明をここに入力](http://sketchtoy.com/)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 太字が荒くなるのは矩形を使って太線を表現しようとしているからだと思います。点と点を結びましょう。座標を保持してスプライン補間を掛ければ綺麗な曲線が作れます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lineJoin`を`'round'`にすれば線と線の継ぎ目が目立たなくなります。また`bezierCurveTo`などの曲線用メソッドも使った方がよいです。

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 30;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(points[0], [1]);
for (var i = 2; i < points.length - 5; i += 4)
{
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(points[i], points[i + 1], points[i + 2], points[i + 3], points[i + 4], points[i + 5]);
}
ctx.stroke();
```